# Apply no wrap to descendants of a th

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that is default `white-space : normal` and want to apply `white-space: nowrap` for all td element linked to a specific th, but not having to apply it on the `<td>` element itself , instead using an external css file.

In example below, i want only the column with id 'my_code' has nowrap.

```
<tr>
 <th id="my_code">Code</th>
 <th id="my_name">Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Your name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>Other name</td>
</tr>
```

I tried this :

```
#my_code {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

And this :

```
#my_code td {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

But won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot target CSS selector to the `td` which is in the same column of the`th` with class or id, since they have no direct relations. But in your example above you can apply:

```
td:nth-child(1) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or, use selector `td:first-of-type`, or `td:first-child` ...

In general, the other way is to use `<col>` elements.

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="class1">
    <col class="class2">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    ...

.class1 { /* your style */ }
```

That will apply the CSS to the entire column. But the allowed style is very limited, only these `background-color`, `border`, `width`, and `visibility` properties are allowed as far as I know.

### Update

With CSS Selectors Level 4, you'll be able to do it with table pseudos:

[**15.1. Column combinator (||)**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-column-combinator)

> The column combinator, which consists of two pipes (||
>   ) represents the relationship of a column element to a cell element belonging to the column it represents.

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="class1">
    <col class="class2">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    ...

.class1 || td {
  /* your style */
}
```

At the time of this writing, this selector is not supported by any browser yet.